# Disallowed MIME type (“text/html”) error - Angular Github pages

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

I just deployed an Angular 8 project to my Github repository but nothing gets displayed on the Github page but I see an error on the browser console.

On Firefox the error says:

`Loading module from “https://theotherspace.illiteratibooksandcoffee.com/theotherspace/runtime-es2015.27965c48d77c449cb93c.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).`

and on Chrome:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Below are the screenshots:

[image: firefox error]
[image: Chrome error]

Comment: I do not see any issue or error in console. Was the issue solved? If not - try to clean up browser cache :)

Comment: I still see the error, it won't even render the page because of it.

Comment: I tried some of the solutions mentioned in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30835 but with no luck. See if it helps for your project.

Answer (score 12):

I had the similar issue as I was using Github pages from a different repository (than the parent github.io repo).

By changing the `base href` to the current directory solved the issue.

Earlier

```
<base href="/">
```

Change to

```
<base href="./">
```

I referred to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30835 until I arrived at this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was working on a nextjs + typescript project and had the exactly same problem.
I solved it by adding `an empty .nojekyll file` to the target folder (same as github pages deployment settings).

I've been searching for days until I arrived at this solution. Hope it will help someone who is also in trouble.

The source I found was in Japanese, but this English one has more details.
https://til.simonwillison.net/github/github-pages

Comment: Wow, thanks. It saved my day, simply by adding the `.nojekyll` to the root. Tested with Nuxt3 btw.