# Blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: html, npm, three.js, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy a website using GitHub Pages. For some reason the JavaScript files will not load and I get the following error.

```
mywebsite.github.io/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)
```

For some reason it believes that the .js file is a html file.

I am using `<base href=".">` as the base href as this was found to be the issue here [Disallowed MIME type (“text/html”) error - Angular Github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047455/disallowed-mime-type-text-html-error-angular-github-pages)

I am loading the js script like so `<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>`

Within `main.js` I am importing like so:

```
import './style.css';

import {OrbitControls} from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import * as THREE from '../node_modules/three/build/three.js';
```

I have tried various file paths such as `/`, `./`, `../` and I am having no luck.

My folder structure is looking like this.

[image]

I've also tried adding an empty .nojekyll file as apparently this may prevent gh-pages from excluding `node_modules`, I've also added `!node_modules` to my .gitignore.

Any help would be appreciated.